# fuel damaged body panel, how to repair?

Tags: oil, body-work

[image]Was in the process of filling up with fuel until I forgot what I was doing and sprayed fuel over body panel/fuel cap area.
Has been there for 2 weeks now and looks quite bad, it seems the oil has merged with the paint.  Car wash weren't able to help.

Is there a way I can remove this diy or will it be difficult\do I need to take to garage?

If the answer is a respray, until that point, is there anything I can do in the meantime to improve the appearance a bit i.e I dont mind if it looks bad but if i can get rid of those white dots that may help.

Comment: Remove paint back to bare metal & respray properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly that really does not look too bad.

Try a good polish yourself with a proper coumpound and a good clean microfiber towel.
I could recommend to buy a suite of polish, coumpounds and power tools but since you have no experience in that area, it could be worse since power tools can eat through clear/paint.

So the best way for you is to apply some dabs of cutting coumpound of the panel, get some on your micro fiber towel and just start rubbing !
Once most of the stain has disappeared, a good polish will give your clear its shine back. Be warned this process is long and hard on the arms (around 1 to 5 hours rubbing).

The only risk is that the other panels will look bad compared to the one you worked on. :)

http://www.performancemotorcare.com/blog/how-to-polish-a-car-by-hand/